# Examples of (not recommendations for) Message Submission Agent (MSA) software

Tags: email, mail-transport-agent

From the Wikipedia articles [*email*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Email&oldid=730625285#Operation) and [*email agent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Email_agent_%28infrastructure%29&oldid=675906975#Classification), I gather that there exist software packages known as **message submission agents** (aka **mail submission agents**).

The Wikipedia article on [message submission agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_submission_agent) does not provide any specific examples of software implementing MSA functionality. It notes that "MTAs [can] perform the function of an MSA", but also that:

> there are ... programs that are specially designed as MSAs without full MTA functionality.

I would be grateful for *examples* of such software that are available for Unix or POSIX operating systems, especially examples that are packaged for one or more GNU/Linux distributions. The name of the piece of software, plus some evidence that it is indeed an MSA and available for Unix/POSIX, is all that is required. Feel free to include a small amount of additional explanation if you wish.

In the event that multiple answers are posted, I will up-vote all accurate and on-topic answers, and will accept the most comprehensive of these answers as correct.

Note: I am *not* asking for recommendations, endorsements, or opinions, so I believe this question is [on-topic here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).